# How to pass parameter in URL in SPFx React

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react

I want to pass parameter in url in SPFx React to redirect my webpart to that url

Comment: Do you want to create a hyperlink with query string parameters within your web part? Can you explain your requirements in detail?

Comment: I want to direct one web part to another web part  through click event and want to take some parameter into url of second web part so that on load the information can be loaded on basis of that prameter.